# $B$ symmetric, then exists $\lambda\ge 0$ such that $B+\lambda I$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Show that if $B$ is symmetric, then there exists $\lambda\ge 0$ such that $B+\lambda I$ is positive definite

I'm reading a proof of this:

[image]

And I have a problem in the part

$$B+\lambda I = Q(A+\epsilon I)Q^T$$

I know that $B+\lambda I = QAQ^T + \lambda I$, and we can certainly do a decomposition $I(\lambda I)I^T$ because $\lambda I$ is already in the desired form. But I don't think we can do $\lambda I = Q(\lambda I)Q^T$ as in the solution

Comment: $B+\lambda I = QAQ^T + \lambda  I = QAQ^T + \lambda   QQ^T = Q(A+\lambda I) Q^T$  since $Q^T = Q^{-1}$.

Comment: @AlanMuniz so by definition $Q^T=Q^{-1}$ in this $QAQ^T$ decomposition? What is the name of this decomposition?

Comment: It follows from the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem Actually it states that $A$ and $B$ are similar, hence $B= QAQ^{-1}$. But in fact $Q$ is orthogonal, hence $Q^{-1} = Q^T$.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the solution, we should have $Q(\Lambda + \lambda I) Q^T$ (as Alan showed us) instead of $Q(\Lambda + \epsilon I) Q^T$. The eigenvalues would be $(\lambda_1 - \lambda_1) + \epsilon, (\lambda_2 - \lambda_1) + \epsilon, \cdots, (\lambda_n - \lambda_1) + \epsilon $ then, which are all positve too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not require anything like diagonalization. If $\lambda > \|B\|$ then $\langle Bx, x \rangle +\lambda \langle x, x \rangle \geq \lambda \|x\|^{2}-\|B\|\|x\|^{2} \geq 0$.